# Merge the "logs" tag with "logging"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

Since there are to few high rep poeple, I suggests here another tag merge:

Should ["logs"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logs) become a synonym of ["logging"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logging)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[call-log](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-log), [call-logs](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-logs), [call-logging](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-logging) -> [call-history](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-history)

[history](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) was removed, [browser-history](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser-history) created

[logcat](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logcat) -> [logging](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logging), which is now used for system and other miscellaneous logging

[logs](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logs) was removed, I figure it's too ambiguous to be merged with anything else